# Combining plotly plots with highly variable widths

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, subplot, gridextra

I want to combine several `R` `plotly` `heatmap`s, using `plotly`'s `subplot`, with some a-priori defined width per each `subplot`, and these widths are highly variable, since they reflect real proportions of my data.

Here's an example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(grDevices)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(row = rep(paste0("rid",1:100),10),
                 col = paste0("cid",unlist(lapply(1:10,function(x) rep(x,100)))),
                 val = rnorm(1000,-2,1))
```

Here I generate the list of plots:

```
plot.list <- lapply(1:10,function(i) plot_ly(z=c(dplyr::filter(df,col == paste0("cid",i))$val),x=dplyr::filter(df,col == paste0("cid",i))$col,y=dplyr::filter(df,col == paste0("cid",i))$row,
                                  colors=colorRamp(c("darkblue","lightgray","darkred")),type="heatmap") %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title=NULL),xaxis=list(tickvals=i,ticktext=as.character(i))))
```

Here are the plot widths:

```
plot.widths <- c(0.33277,0.0663,0.28308,0.09323,0.12969,0.0603,0.00651,0.01149,0.01503,0.0016)
```

Clearly, they sum up to 1.

If I just try this:

```
subplot(plot.list,shareX=T,shareY=T,nrows=1,margin=0.001,widths=plot.widths) %>% layout(showlegend=F)
```

I get:
[image]

I realized that the plot widths that are smaller than 0.015 cause this.

Right now my quick fix is to scale up the widths of the plots that are below 0.015 and to reciprocally scale down the widths of the plots that are above 0.015 so that the minimal plot width is 0.015 and they still sum up to 1.

Like this:

```
below.cutoff.widths <- which(plot.widths < 0.015)
if(length(below.cutoff.widths) > 0){
  scale.up.factor <- 0.015/min(plot.widths[below.cutoff.widths])
  scale.down.factor <- sum(plot.widths[-below.cutoff.widths])/(1-sum(scale.up.factor*(plot.widths[below.cutoff.widths])))
  plot.widths[-below.cutoff.widths] <- plot.widths[-below.cutoff.widths]/scale.down.factor
  plot.widths[below.cutoff.widths] <- plot.widths[below.cutoff.widths]*scale.up.factor
  plot.widths <- plot.widths-.Machine$double.eps
}
```

Which works and gives:
[image]

The problem is that in the example above this significantly distorts the original widths and therefore distorts the message that I'm trying to convey with this plot.

Any idea how to handle this better?

I don't suppose there's a way to simply convert the `plot.list`'s `plotly` objects to `ggplot` objects and use `gridExtra`'s `arrangeGrob` to arrange them together on a grid?

Comment: this is really similar to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455176/faceting-heatmaps-in-plotly-with-variable-widths?rq=1) of yours. Maybe you could use `ggplotly`and `cowplot`.

Comment: Converting rich heatmaps to `ggplot` objects with `ggplotly` is very inefficient